# Конвертация JPG в PDF в Ghostscript

Tags: cmd, bat, ghostscript

Насколько я знаю, Ghostscript не поддерживает конвертацию файлов по маске (*) из отдельной команды, и все файлы надо явно перечислять (0001.jpg, 0002.jpg). Попался такой скрипт, содержащий конвертацию по маске, но не удалось выяснить, по какой причине он не работает, просьба подсказать.

```
echo
dir="F:\myFolder"
output_file="F:\myFolder\out.pdf"
pause

args=""

for file in `find ${dir} -name "*.JPG" -o -name "*.JPEG" -o -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" -type f`;
do
  args="${args} (${file}) viewJPEG showpage"
done


"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.01.1\bin\gswin32c.exe" -q -dNOSAFER -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=${output_file} "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.01.1\lib\viewjpeg.ps" -c ${args}
```

Comment: Ну так сделай каталог с 2-3 файлами, закомментируй @echo off, добавь echo в начало строки запуска конвертора, запусти и посмотри, что идёт не так...

Comment: Две непонятные строки с Error:
Error: /undefined in ????
GPL Ghostscript 10.01.1: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: Ты echo перед gswin32c.exe добавил? походу нет... с ним ты увидишь, какую команду пытается запустить батник..

Comment: Конечно добавил, иначе я не увидел бы сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: В скрипте при выведенной в эхо команде нет в принципе ничего, что могло бы породить подобное сообщение об ошибке... ведь всё остальное - это варится внутри выполнения скрипта, а у тебя явно стартует Ghostscript

Comment: Вот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KYxn.png проверяй правильность выполняемой команды.

Comment: У меня это окно отличается: https://i.imgur.com/TDzut2C.png Впрочем, я поменял код на другой - как мне кажется, более правильный - учитывающий регистр расширений и тп., но он тоже не срабатывает. Выводится ошибка про неизвестную команду "${output_file}"

Comment: Как я и говорю - ты не поставил echo в начале строки запуска gswin32c.exe, поэтому у тебя и запускается процесс конвертации. Впрочем, на твоём скрине сама выполняемая команда хорошо видна. Вот её и надо отладить - то есть чётко проглядеть все её параметры и отрихтовать до нужного состояния. А потом соответствующим образом поправить текст батника.